# Can I test my IPN listener VB.NET code under localhost (ASP.NET Web Forms)?

Tags: paypal-ipn

The 'Local development testing' section of PayPal's [IPN Testing](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/IPNTesting/) page implies that it is possible to test your IPN listener code via localhost, using a test page to simulate a message from PayPal.

My TestIPN.aspx page contains the following markup, which appears to follow the example provided by PayPal, but when I open it in Firefox under localhost (via Visual Studio 2019) and click the Submit Query button I get a 'File not found' error for https://localhost:44390/PayPal/IPNHandler.aspx.vb.

Needless to say, IPNHandler.aspx.vb *does* exist in my PayPal folder (using *"PayPal/IPNHandler.aspx"* in the form tag on my test page makes no difference). I also get the same error when I run it on my live site.

Any guidance on how to debug this problem would be much appreciated.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test IPN message</title>
</head>
<body>
 <!--
 <form target="_new" method="post" action="https://www.YourDomain.com/Path/YourIPNHandler.php">    
 -->
    <form target="_new" method="post" action="PayPal/IPNHandler.aspx.vb">
      <input type="hidden" name="receiver_email" value="admin%40mysite.co.uk"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="business" value="admin%40mysite.co.uk"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="Fred"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Bloggs"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="payer_email" value="fred.bloggs%40gmail.com"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="address_city" value="Southampton"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="payment_type" value="instant"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="payment_date" value="19:54:19 Apr 12, 2021 GMT"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="payment_status" value="Completed"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="mc_currency" value="GBP"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="mc_gross" value="5.00"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="25"/>

      <input type="submit"/>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I get a 'File not found' error for https://localhost:44390/PayPal/IPNHandler.aspx.vb

Is that the correct port? What happens if you put  `https://localhost:44390/PayPal/IPNHandler.aspx.vb` in the URL bar?  Use a URL that works to the handler on your localhost, which does not return a 404. Set the `action` accordingly.

Consider something like https://ngrok.com for testing as well.

---

Why are you integrating IPN anyway? It's 20 or so years old, and not required for current PayPal Checkout integrations you should be using instead...

Follow the [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). Both routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with the frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Hi Preston,
Thanks for taking the time to respond to my question. I must admit that I was puzzled by the apparent need for the form action to access a handler page that is not intended for viewing by the user. Trying to use the URL https://localhost:44390/PayPal/IPNHandler.aspx.vb never seems to work. Perhaps things are different when using php (about which I know nothing), which was assumed by PayPal's original sample IPN message.

Comment: It's for mock/testing purposes only. By submitting the test form, you are simulating a message being sent by PayPal to your IPN notify/listener URL.

Comment: My best advice remains to not use IPN for anything and switch to a current PayPal Checkout integration (see the Set up standard payments guide, above)

Comment: I was aiming to use IPN because that's what worked for me back in 2008 for a site that ran successfully for many years. My recent searches also suggested that IPN was still a recommended solution. However, I will now take a closer look at the alternative you mentioned.

Comment: Your second PayPal link seems to depend on me paying for the PayPal Commerce Platform. I'm developing a site for a small non-profit organisation to make it easier to pay membership fees. I need a free solution.

Comment: Not sure where you're getting that idea, but no; standard PayPal processing fee applies

Comment: Your second PayPal link to 'Make API calls from your server' is a page associated with the Paypal Commerce Platform

Comment: And as I said, the standard PayPal processing fees apply. I'm not sure where you're getting any ideas otherwise.

Comment: Something I read a few days ago gave me the impression that the Paypal Commerce Platform required additional fees beyond the standard PayPal processing fees. I must have misunderstood.